# Duplicate array items getting appended in Response (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am using two APIs, one for fetching the Cars added by the user and the second to (Adding new car) submit the car details into my backend. When I open the View of the car details,  all 11 Car details are getting fetched properly.

But when I submit the car details (Add New Car) by clicking the add rounded button and the fetch the details of the added car it shows 22 car added in the frontend Table View but now in the backend of the API.

Here are some screenshots.

1. Before adding a new car

[image: Before adding new Car (11 Cars)]

2. After adding a new car

[image: After adding new Car (22 Cars)]

Here is the code for the same.

Below function is getting used in Viewdidload to fetch the details:

```
func responsedatavehicle(){
        let emailid =  defaults.string(forKey: "email")
             
             var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/getMyVehicleInfo?email=\(emailid!)")!)
             print("Email in resposfunction \(emailid!)")
             request.httpMethod = "GET"
             request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
             request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
             
             do{
                 
                 //            let postString = "?mobile="+ph!
                 print("mobno is inside getdata \(emailid!)")
                 
                 //            //print(postString)
                 //            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
                 APESuperHUD.show(style: .loadingIndicator(type: .standard), title: nil, message: "Loading...")
                 //self.activityIndicator("Please Wait")
             }catch let error{
                 //print(error.localizedDescription)
                 return
             }
             
             //        self.activityIndicator("Please Wait")
             
             let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                 data, response, error in
                 if error != nil
                 {
                     return
                 }
                 let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                 do{
                     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                     if let parseJSON = json{
                         print(parseJSON)
                         if let mobile = parseJSON["error"] as! Int? {
                             let msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                             if (mobile == 0){
                                 
                                 
                                 //print(userId)
                                 
                                 
                                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                     //                                self.showGlobalAlertwithMessage(msg as! NSString)
                                     if let heroeArray = json!.value(forKey: "content") as? Array<[String:Any]> {
                                         //looping through all the elements
                                         self.labelArray.append(contentsOf: heroeArray)
                                     }
                                     APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true)
                                     //    self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
                                     //print(self.labelArray.count)
                                     
                                     for i in 0..<self.labelArray.count{
                                         if let heroeDict = self.labelArray[i] as? NSDictionary{
                                             //                                        let stationname = heroeDict.value(forKey: "charging_station") as! String
                                             let brandname = heroeDict.value(forKey: "brand_name") as! String
                                             let modelname = heroeDict.value(forKey: "car_name") as! String
                                             let accharger = heroeDict.value(forKey: "ac_charger") as! String
                                             let dccharger = heroeDict.value(forKey: "dc_charger") as! String
                                             let vehiclenumber = heroeDict.value(forKey: "vehicle_registration_number") as! String
                                            
                                           let imageurl = heroeDict.value(forKey: "vehicle_photo") as! String
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                             self.brandnamearray.append(brandname)
                                             self.modelnamearray.append(modelname)
                                             self.acchargerarray.append(accharger)
                                             self.dcchargerarray.append(dccharger)

                                            self.imageurlarray.append(imageurl)
                                           self.vehiclenoarray.append(vehiclenumber)
                                          
                                             
                                            print(self.imageurlarray)
                                          
                                         }
                                     }
                                     self.myTableView.reloadWithAnimation()
                                 }
                                 
                             }else {
                                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                     //self.showGlobalAlertwithMessage(msg as! NSString)
                                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                         APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true)
                                         // self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     } else{
                       print("ERROR IN ALERT")
                     }
                 }
                 catch{
                     //                self.showGlobalAlertwithMessage("Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
                 }
             }
             task.resume()
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Cellforrowat Function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyVehicleTableViewCell
        
                cell.brandnamecell.text = brandnamearray[indexPath.row]
                cell.modelnamecell.text = modelnamearray[indexPath.row]
                cell.acchargercell.text = acchargerarray[indexPath.row]
                cell.dcchargercell.text = dcchargerarray[indexPath.row]
                cell.vehiclenumbercell.text = vehiclenoarray[indexPath.row]
       
            cell.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageurlarray[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        cell.aclabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        cell.aclabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.aclabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.aclabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.dclabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        cell.dclabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.dclabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.dclabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                      cell.aclabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                     cell.aclabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
              cell.aclabel.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
                   cell.aclabel.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
                   cell.aclabel.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:     cell.aclabel.bounds).cgPath
                    cell.aclabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
         
                           cell.dclabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                          cell.dclabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                   cell.dclabel.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
                        cell.dclabel.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
                        cell.dclabel.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:     cell.dclabel.bounds).cgPath
                         cell.dclabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        
        
        
        cell.backview.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.98, alpha:0.9).cgColor
        cell.backview.layer.cornerRadius = 8
               cell.backview.layer.masksToBounds = true
               cell.backview.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
               
        
        cell.shadowmodel.layer.cornerRadius = 13.0
                  cell.shadowmodel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                  cell.shadowmodel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                cell.shadowmodel.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
                  cell.shadowmodel.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
                 cell.shadowmodel.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:     cell.shadowmodel.bounds).cgPath
                cell.shadowmodel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        
        return cell
     }
```

Below function is getting used to add a new car:

```
 func submitcar(){
        if vehiclenumberstring == ""{
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Please enter vehicle number ") // Error

        }
        else {
        let emailsubmit =  defaults.string(forKey: "email")
        print("email inside submit car is \(emailsubmit!)")
                var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/apimobileapps/addVehicleInfo")!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                
                do{
                    let postString = "brand_name="+brandname+"&car_name="+modelname+"&vehicle_registration_number="+vehiclenumberstring+"&email="+emailsubmit!
                    print(postString)
                    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
                    APESuperHUD.show(style: .loadingIndicator(type: .standard), title: nil, message: "Loading...")
                 //   self.activityIndicator("Please Wait")
                }catch let error{
                    //print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
                    (data, response, error) in
                    
                    if (error != nil){
                        return
                    }
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                        if let parseJSON = json{
                            //print(parseJSON)
                            if let userId = parseJSON["error"] as! Int? {
                                let msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                                if (userId == 0){
                                    //print(userId)
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //                                self.showGlobalAlertwithMessage(msg as! NSString)
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true); self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
                                        
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //                                self.showGlobalAlertwithMessage(msg as! NSString)
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true)
                                           // self.effectView.removeFromSuperview();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        } else{
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true)
                           //     self.effectView.removeFromSuperview();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }catch{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            APESuperHUD.dismissAll(animated: true)
                     //       self.effectView.removeFromSuperview();
                        }
                        //print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
                task.resume()
        }
        responsedatavehicle()

    }
```

My Array count is showing duplicate values in the table view on submit button action.

Comment: Why are you doing `DispatchQueue.main.async` from inside the closure for `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: I am using the inside one to dismiss the activity indicated . I dont think this is related to the duplicate array items @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Where do you reset your arrays ? There is only code that append to the arrays. To simplify you could also use  struct or class instead of multiple arrays.

Comment: @PtitXav i am reseting my array at cellforrow at function . I have updated the code above . Please check . Also i prefer to use arrays . Please help me towards my problem ;(

Comment: At the end of submitcar you call responsedatavehicle which add the received véhicules in the current arrays without resetting them.

Comment: @PtitXav if i remove that function in the end of the submit , then the new added car is not displayed after reloading the table view . What should i do in such case?

Comment: in submitcar, add the car to your arrays before reloading the tableview .